# How can I keep text on the same line as an icon?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

```
  <div className={'bg-blue-700 flex flex-row p-5 items-center justify-between'} >
     <div>
        <IconButton className={'bg-blue-900 p-5 hover:bg-blue-900 '}>
            <Phone className={'text-white'} />
        </IconButton>
        <div className="text-white">John Doe</div>
      </div>
      <div>
          
      </div>
</div>
```

The problem its John Doe its going to the next row.

[image]

This is the look I want to achieve.

[image]

thank you in advance.

Comment: Add flex to div which has `iconButton` as child i.e. second div in your code.

Comment: weird that work, but I don't get it at the top I said all my member should be flex in the parent. what do i have to say flex again in the child

Comment: If you make an element flex, only your child element can use flex properties not all the descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `div` tag that wraps the icon and the name elements, so that those are direct children of the `flex` div. The way you have it now only that in-between wrapper div is a flex item, its children won't be affected by the flex setting of their grandparent element.